# How to display two components horizontally

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { NavBar } from './NavBar.js';
import {Parent} from './Parent.js';

class ProfilePage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
                 <NavBar />
                 <Parent />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ProfilePage />, document.getElementById('root') );
```

I am trying to display `NavBar` and `Parent` horizontally. I tried it with the `flexDirection:'row'` but it didn't work. Can someone help me to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add some code for `NavBar` and `Parent` ? and the screenshot too

Answer (score 0):

To work with flexbox you need a display flex parent

So you can wrap those two components into one div
And then add  display flex to that div and apply 
flex-direction: row; to parent div, it should work, or
If you don't want use flexbox so add display: inline-block
for every wrapper component

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?
I've used `flex` & `flex-direction: column` to make the 2 parts to be one above the other.

Pay attention that content was stretched to take the remaining area, that was done by `flex: 1 1 auto`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

nav {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

main {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Lin 1</li>
      <li>Link 2</li>
      <li>Link 3</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
    content
  </main>
</div>
```